# Фильтры в Web-приложении Java

Tags: java, filter

В приложении есть набор страниц, вход на которые разрешается только авторизованным пользователям, набор страниц, вход на которые разрешается 
только неавторизованным пользователям, и страницы, доступные всем. В фильтре требуется организовать проверку сессии пользователя, в которой хранится его id, и имеет ли он доступ к запрашиваемому ресурсу. Это лучше организовать цепочкой из нескольких фильтров или в одном все лучше делать, учитывая, что при каждом запросе полученный из сессии id сверяется по базе на наличие такого пользователя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше всего взять готовую реализацию, например [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/). Это проверенное в бою решение.

Если это почему-то невозможно, можно воспользоваться паттерном, аналогичным тому, что используется в SpringSecurity: делаете filter-class, который будет работать как прокси, и при инициализации принимает цепочку других фильтров, [как описано здесь](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/reference/security-filter-chain.html). В результате web.xml не перегружен мусором, а вы можете удобно управлять цепочкой фильтров.

Вообще, когда вопрос начинает ставиться как "все делать в одном", мы скорей всего имеем дело с (анти)паттерном [God Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). Интуиция ооп-программиста должна в этом месте бить тревогу, сигнализируя что делать так нужно только в случае необходимости предварительной оптимизации.

Comment: Я могу использовать Spring Security только для организации прав доступа, или это потребует внедрения дополнительных частей spring-фреймворка?

Comment: @carapuz, я сам не пробовал (мы очень зависим от Spring), но по логике вещей это вполне возможно.

Например, вот вопрос на английской вики, работает ли Spring Security вне SpringMVC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838756/spring-security-without-spring-mvc.

А вот тут утверждают, что оно работает даже без Servlet API: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-use-Spring-Security-without-Servlet-API

Но с этим нужно, конечно, разбираться.

Я попробую разобраться, но это точно будет не сейчас.
Если у вас это получится раньше, напишите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Для доступа именно к отдельным ссылкам можно использовать довольно молодую технологию HDIV. Она легко подстраивается под архитектуру MVC и в моем случае пока, что отлично работает. Кроме этого предоставляет функции защиты от хаккинга(инъекций, ддоса и тому подобное). Более подробно об этом вы можете рассмотреть в самом исходном коде и почитать инструкции с [репозитория](https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv-spring-mvc-showcase) на гите.